# layout issue while changing java code

Tags: java, eclipse, layout

I'm currently trying to modify a java project `TRMSim_WSN` (Simulator) using Eclipse. 
I changed some parts of the source code but the layout seems like it has changed even though I didn't touch it!

[The original one:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkRJl.jpg)

[After modifying:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSVZu.jpg)

Can you help me please?

Comment: The `legend` area seems to be a JComponent of some kind. Can you post the java code for this Component from your source. Also, check to see if some resources (like the images) are missing

Comment: Reverse all of your changes.  Make one change and test.  If your test fails, reverse that change.  **Make one change at a time.**

Comment: @jr593 I don't think there are missing resources, it's seems they are disordered but I couldn't see why!

Comment: @jr593 I just posted the code. Thank you!

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Actually I tried this solution and I repeated the whole thinf step by step but It didn't help! 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts for this component:
The 1st one:

```
this.legendPanelContainer.add(this.legendPanel, null);
this.legendPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
this.legendPanelContainer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 98));

GroupLayout legendPanelContainerLayout = new GroupLayout(this.legendPanelContainer);
this.legendPanelContainer.setLayout(legendPanelContainerLayout);
legendPanelContainerLayout.setHorizontalGroup(legendPanelContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 100, 32767));

legendPanelContainerLayout.setVerticalGroup(legendPanelContainerLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 81, 32767));

this.legendLabel.setText("Legend");
this.legendLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 15));
```

The 2nd one:

```
this.legendPanelContainer.add(this.legendPanel, null);
this.legendPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
this.legendPanel.setSize(this.legendPanelContainer.getSize());
this.legendPanel.plotLegend();
```

The problem is that I don't see any difference between the source code and the one I modified for this part!